# Fetching JSON data in flutter returns NULL

Tags: php, json, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and trying to get data from a hosted php file. The results return NULL no matter what I try.. I would like to output all data in the php file also not just one row. on PHP I would just do a for loop to get all the JSON data. How would I do that in Dart?

my PHP file -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_log";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $rows = array();
        while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $r;
        }
        $newArray = array_values($rows);
    }
$json_string = json_encode($newArray, true);

echo $json_string;
```

Dart Code -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    String name, team;


FetchJSON() async {
    var url = 'https://vettx.app/api/get.php';
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    name = data['0']['user'];
    team = data['0']['team'];
    //print(data.toString());
}

void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FetchJSON();
}

Widget MyUI() {
  return new Container(
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
        new Text(
           'Name : $name',
        ),
        new Text(
          'Team : $team',
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Get Data'),
      ),
      body: isData
          ? new Center(
        child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
          : MyUI(),
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

JSON data -

```
{
    "id": "4037",
    "user_id": "1",
    "user": "Ryan Dietz",
    "team": "Manager",
    "action": "email",
    "veh_id": "73366",
    "user_notes": "I am wondering if you have the VIN by chance?",
    "time_stamp": "2020-03-26 20:27:07"
},
```

Link to JSON Example -

```
https://vettx.app/api/get.php
```

Comment: Your json is not returning list so try data['user] to access user.

Comment: Yeah no luck, if you look at the example php link the json data has a parent level of [0]

Comment: http.get(url).then((response){   var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    name = data['0']['user'];
    team = data['0']['team'];  }); try this

Comment: Still returns NULL, if I print(data.toString()); it outputs all the data to the log which really confuses me why it returns NULL to the screen.

Comment: Remove  single quotes (') from around zero. data[0]['user']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server returns an array of objects, so you need to parse the json and store it in an array. Also to get 0th index you need to write `array[0]`, not `array['0']`.

Instead of storing first object properties, you have to return the entire array back from the fetchJSON method:

```
Future<List> fetchJSON() async {
   var url = 'https://vettx.app/api/get.php';
   http.Response response = await http.get(url);
   var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
   return data;
}
```

Use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget to handle the loading and displaying of the data as shown below:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Get Data'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List>(
        future: fetchJSON(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              // Success case
              return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index]['user']),
                    subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index]['team']),
                    trailing: Text(snapshot.data[index]['id']),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              );
            }
            // Error case
            return Text('Something went wrong');
          } else {
            // Loading data
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

In the above code snapshot.data will be a list of objects, you can use the index value of itemBuilder to loop through that.

And the final output will be like:

[image: Output]